# ValueError: could not convert string to float when training in keras

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'm trying to run a basic neural net using keras:

```
import numpy
    import pandas
    from keras.models import *
    from keras.layers import *
    from keras.optimizers import *

    dataframe = pandas.read_csv("data/mydata.csv", header=None) 
    dataset = dataframe.values
    # split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
    X = dataset[:,0:21] #X features 
    Y = dataset[:,21] # Y labels

#Define Neural network model of 10 Hidden layer with 500 Neurons each
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500, input_dim=21, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Input Layer 
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 1
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden layer 2
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 3
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 4
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 5
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 6
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 7
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 8
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 9
model.add(Dense(500, init='normal', activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer 10
model.add(Dense(1, init='normal', activation='sigmoid')) #Output later
print('Modeled Network')

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'] ) 
 #fits the data point X, Y to the model
model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.3, shuffle=True, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=5000)

# serialize model to JSON
print("* Saving model to disk..")
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("models/model.json", "w") as json_file:
  json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("models/model.h5")
```

However, I'm getting the error:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'feature21'` during compilation. I'm pretty new to this so I'm not sure why it would be trying to convert a string to a float since headers are turned off in the data set and the feature itself is entirely numeric. Is there already a known easy solution to this?

Comment: I suggest you check that yourself to be sure. It's very likely that X or Y have some string value in them. Also, usually the arrays should be numpy arrays, so if you transform them to numpy arrays it may be of use.

Comment: Also, it sounds like X has shape (batch, 50), and your model is expecting shape (batch, 23) because of `input_dim=23`.

Comment: @Daniel I'm certain at the very least that the .csv file has values of the form 0.12345 throughout. Transforming them may work though, what do you think would be the best option for that?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry that's just an older version of the code, the datasets actually only have 21, that was from when I was using a different set.

Comment: I suggest you do: `for row in X: for item in row: if isinstance(item,basestring): print("got a string here")`. The same goes for Y with a smaller loop.

Comment: I got the same error, it's because the labels are strings rather than integers ..